# Python io.UnsupportedOperation: not writable error when trying to use the sum of two values as a row counter

Tags: python

I am total Python noob. I'm attempting to read in the most recent (6-9) csv files from a directory, and append them to a master file, so the newest data is on top (still need to add that functionality). The files range in number of rows from about a few thousand to 100,000+ rows. The master/archive file needs to be < 800,000 total rows.

My current code is attempting to create a new file, incremented by 1, when the rows in the archive + lines read from the input files reaches 750,000 rows. The codes reads and writes the correct files; however, the row counter is not working properly.

Currently, it would only create a new file if the total rows read in from an input file (read_row_count) is over 750,000 rows. I get an io.UnsupportedOperation: not writable error if I try to assign the archive_row_count += read_row_count and use the new archive_row_count as the comparison to the max_rows. I've tried several different ways and can't seem to figure it out.

python version 3.9.10 using anaconda

I know the "io.UnsupportedOperation: not writable" has been asked and answered many times on here, but those solutions don't seem to be relevant. I've tried using a and a+ open modes in the archive file, and even tried opening the files I want to read in r+ for s and giggles, which I don't want to write to these files at all, and then I get a "io.UnsupportedOperation: not readable" error if I change those modes.

I only get this error when using the archive_row_count variable, even if I assign it a static value.

```
import os
import glob


def write_files_to_new_file(dump_directory,archive_directory,report):
    # max lines per file
    max_rows = 750000
    # initializers
    read_row_count = 0
    file_index = 1

    # path to archive/output file
    archive_path = os.path.join(archive_directory, report)
    archive_file = f'{archive_path} {file_index}.csv'
    # archive_row_count = 0
    archive_row_count = sum(1 for l in archive_file)

    all_files = sorted(glob.glob(os.path.join(dump_directory, "*")), key=os.path.getmtime, reverse=True)

    # Select most recent files - 3 files per 3 database (invoice only has 90-45 & 45-0)
    if report == i_report:
        recent_files = all_files[:6]
    else:
        recent_files = all_files[:9]

    # open archive file; create if doesn't exist
    with open(archive_file, 'a+', encoding='utf-8') as out_file:
        # archive_row_count = sum(1 for l in archive_file)
        for file_path in recent_files:
            with open(file_path, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as in_file:
                print("Reading file: ", file_path)
                for line in in_file:
                    out_file.write(line)
                    read_row_count +=1
                    # add number of rows in archive file to rows read
                    archive_row_count += read_row_count # io.UnsupportedOperation: not writable error
                    # read_row_count += archive_row_count # io.UnsupportedOperation: not writable error
                    # check if number of rows exceeds the limit; create new file if max rows in archive file is reached
                    if archive_row_count >= max_rows: # io.UnsupportedOperation: not writable error
                    # if read_row_count >= max_rows: # doesn't create new file unless max rows are read from the single file.
                        print(f"Wrote {read_row_count} rows to {archive_file}. Max rows reached - Creating new archive file.")
                        # close current file
                        out_file.close()
                        # increment file index
                        file_index +=1
                        # open a new file for writing
                        out_file = open(archive_file)
                        # reset row count
                        read_row_count = 0
                        
    # close final output file
    out_file.close()
    #archive_file = archive_file.split("\\")[-1]
    print(f"Wrote {read_row_count} rows to {archive_file}")

            

### Tender Accept file variables
ta_in_path = r'C:\Users\me\dir\dir\Test Files\TA Dump' # -- Path to dump directory - place to read files from
ta_out_path = r'C:\Users\me\dir\dir\Test Files\Test Files\TA Archive' # -- Path to archive directory - place to write files to
ta_report = "Master TA Archive" # file prefix

### Shipment file variables
s_in_path = r'C:\Users\me\dir\dir\Test Files\Test Files\Shipment Dump'
s_out_path = r'C:\Users\me\dir\dir\Test Files\Test Files\Shipment Archive'
s_report = "Master Shipment Archive"

### Invoice file variables
i_in_path = r'C:\Users\me\dir\dir\Test Files\Test Files\Invoice Dump'
i_out_path = r'C:\Users\me\dir\dir\Test Files\Test Files\Invoice Archive'
i_report = "Master Invoice Archive"

### Read and append reports into Master files.
write_files_to_new_file(ta_in_path, ta_out_path,ta_report)
write_files_to_new_file(s_in_path, s_out_path,s_report)
write_files_to_new_file(i_in_path, i_out_path,i_report)
```

Hopefully this formatting doesn't get messed up.

Output after I run the code as is:

```
Reading file:  C:\Users\me\dir\dir\Test Files\TA Dump\file1.csv
Reading file:  C:\Users\me\dir\dir\Test Files\TA Dump\file2.csv
Wrote 1225 rows to C:\Users\me\dir\dir\Test Files\TA Archive\Master TA Archive 1.csv. Max rows reached - Creating new archive file.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\me\dir\dir\Test Files\TA Dump\update.py", line 75, in <module>
    write_files_to_new_file(ta_in_path, ta_out_path,ta_report)
  File "c:\Users\me\dir\dir\Test Files\TA Dump\update.py", line 34, in write_files_to_new_file
    out_file.write(line)
io.UnsupportedOperation: not writable
```

It created a new file and started writing to it, but it did not reach 750,000 rows

Comment: Show the full traceback of the error as properly formatted text in the question.

Comment: `out_file = open(archive_file)`. A couple of things here: (1) it opens it in the default read mode (you haven't specified `a+` like the previous place you opened the file), (2) you've incremented `file_index` but you haven't used that new value to recalculate `archive_file` - so your "new" file has the same filename as the original one.

Comment: @slothrop well, adding the a+ to the second file open seems to have fixed that error; however, the code in the if statement is still being executed while the row count is below the max rows. so, it seems like there is something wrong with the archive_row_count counter.

Comment: @crypth3o Right, that's a separate problem. In the innermost loop, you're doing `archive_row_count += read_row_count` once per line.  Let's say the initial value of `archive_row_count` is `a`. After processing 1 line of the input file, `archive_row_count==a+1`. After 2 lines, `read_row_count==2` so `archive_row_count==a+3`. After 3 lines, `read_row_count==3` so `archive_row_count==a+6`... and so on.  You could fix this by doing `archive_row_count += 1` instead of `archive_row_count += read_row_count`.